# $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof for $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (2,3)}(3x-2y)=-4$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, epsilon-delta

I am attempting the proof but encounter a problem as described at the bottom.

Fix arbitrary $\epsilon>0$. Then need to show that there exists a $\delta>0$ such that if $0<\sqrt{(x-2)^2+(y-3)^2}<\delta$, then
\begin{align*}
    |3x-2y+4|&=|3x-2y+4-6+6|\\
    &=|3(x-2)+2(y-3)+4|\\
    &\leq 3|x-2|+2|y-3|+4\\
    &\leq 3\delta +2\delta +4=5\delta+4
\end{align*}
We want $5\delta+4<\epsilon$ so let $\delta=\frac{\epsilon-4}{5}$.
Above, we used that $|x-2|$ and $|y-3|\leq \sqrt{(x-2)^2+(y-3)^2}$

Now fix arbitrary $\epsilon>0$ and choose $\delta=\frac{\epsilon-4}{5}$. Then
\begin{align*}
    0<\sqrt{(x-2)^2+(y-3)^2}<\frac{\epsilon-4}{5}&\implies 5\sqrt{(x-2)^2+(y-3)^2}+4<\epsilon\\
    &\implies 3|x-2|+2|3-y|+4<\epsilon\\
    &\implies |3(x-2)+2(3-y)+4|<\epsilon\\
    &\implies |3x-6+6-2y+4|<\epsilon\\
    &\implies |3x-2y+4|<\epsilon
\end{align*}

But how do we know that $\delta>0$? Say if $\epsilon<4$. How can I rectify this problem?

Comment: Why $-4$? $3(2)-2(3)=0$

Comment: Your limit is 0, not -4. Apply your argument and you have completed the proof.